# Why doesn't Dr. Strange use the time stone to do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of the final battle in *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony is damaged from the snap. All the stones are right there, and there are no bad guys left to distract Dr. Strange.

Why doesn't Dr. Strange use the time stone to reverse Tony's wounds?

Comment: Turning back time would reverse the snap too.

Comment: There is no need to edit the question to hide spoilers. People should expect spoilers when the see the endgame tag.

Comment: Insofar as Tony was affected by **all** the Stones, it's likely that one Stone wouldn't be enough.

Comment: @bobbyalex _"Turning back time would reverse the snap too"_ not necessarily, the Time Stone is proven to only affect a small thing if needed. However, the snap caused his wounds so you're probably right, just wanted to be clear.

Comment: we don't even know if he can, sure he has the time stone but perhaps his powers are a less effective channel then the gauntlet

Comment: @bobbyalex Dr. Strange has been shown to be capable of using the time stone to reverse time for a single object, leaving the rest of the world unaffected. Thanos does the same in Infinity War when he uses the Time Stone to bring back Vision. I don't see any reason to think that using the Time Stone _just_ on Tony would reverse the Snap.

Comment: because _Robert Downey Jr.'s Marvel Contract Ended_.

Comment: @JM haha thats the right answer and he's probably become to expensive !

Comment: Iron Man isn't an apple.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because this is that one win scenario among 14 million futures Doctor Strange saw.

As director Joe Russo [explains](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/),

> Q: In IW, Thanos used the time stone to reverse the time so he could the already dead Vision, and it didn’t cause any time parallax. Why did no one use time stone to save Iron Man’s life in EG?
>
> A: **It’s because even if you save Iron Man, it will still not change the fact that Thanos will eventually win the war. Among the 14 million possibilities that Doctor Strange has seen, Iron Man’s sacrifice is a must for that one win scenario.**

Comment: Doesn't Dr. Strange tell Tony that if he tells him what must happen, it won't happen?

Comment: I can't recall him telling that. However, if this is the case, this statement still stands true. He must have [seen](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100067/27264) that and know how it will go.

Comment: Thank you!  I find this answer deeply unsatisfactory, since it was understood that the *1 in 14 million event* **was** Tony's snap, but since the director wrote it I think this has to be the canonical answer.

Answer (score 8):

If Dr.Strange tries to reverse time on Iron man, then he also reverses the snap and Thanos would be back again.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. The Time Stone can revert time "locally", as seen in IW when Thanos ressurects Vision and in _Doctor Strange_ when the apple goes back from being eaten

Comment: Yes, but the "snap" is what wounds him fatally, if he has to undo the wound, then he has to undo the snap. In Infinity War Thanos undoes Wanda's destruction of the Stone which causes Vision's death. Undoing the destruction of the Stone brings back Vision. Thanos doesn't want Vision alive, he wants only the stone, but the two events are linked.

Comment: To add to that, he can't bring back Gamorah for the same reason, her death and the retreival of the stone are inversely bound just like Vision's death is tied to the stones destruction.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly correct.  Everyone using the Vision example as to supposedly suggest what Dr. Strange could do for Iron Man are disproving their own theory.

-> Thanos wants to turn back time for stone, but must bring back Vision to do so.
-> If strange uses time stone to turn back time for Iron man and undo snap, he must bring back Thanos in order to do so.

Answer (score 3):

### Because there's been more than enough meddling and destruction for one day

By the point that Iron Man defeats Thanos and his minions with his own 'snap', there has already been massive loss of life, risk to the Earth, and interferences in time.

There is an argument here that Doctor Strange could re-appropriate the Time Stone and attempt to use it to reverse the physical damage Stark suffered from using the Infinity Stones. However, if there was *any* risk that such an action could reverse Iron Man's decisive 'snap', then that risk is **simply unacceptable**. Even if Strange was minded to attempt such an action, he would almost certainly have been blocked or dissuaded by the other heroes who would be fearful of re-entering the nightmare scenario of Thanos's invasion again.

The only action that is carried out with the Infinity Stones after Iron Man's 'snap'  is their careful restoration to their various points in time by Captain America, in keeping with the original 'time heist' plan.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Hulk's damages, Joe Russo told :

> He's lost an arm (...) That's permanent damage, the same way it was permanent damage with Thanos: It's irreversible damage.

From that we can conclude that even if Thanos didn't heal himself after the first snap in IW, that suggest that Time Stone can't manage to heal wound caused by Stones themself.

Time Stone alone can't undo what multiple stones did.

Answer (score 1):

Doctor Strange had watched 14,000,605 possibilities and their was only one scenario in which they won.Let's assume for a moment that Dr.Strange did restored tony's wounds, and Tony Stark lives ... what would happen then? Tony is the 'Futurist' in the MCU and he can't help but keep thinking on how to make the world a better place but we did saw where his intelligence led (Ultron was his fault and all the death caused by Ultron is ultimately on him..... Then he forced the avengers to keep together while he could have done that by explaining the future risks he feared and trusting his freinds...and as Cap said that tony tries to win the war before it starts and people end up dying and it's all their fault.....). I'm not a hater of Tony Stark, he is definitely a great character and its his flaws and mistakes that make him able to learn. But Dr.Strange might have saw a danger in Tony being alive. Moreover, messing with time can break the space time continnum as explained in MCU. Maybe there is more to the character of Tony Stark than just being alive. Maybe he can become a symbol or return as a fully independent working A.I Tony Stark n fill in the gap created by Tony himself. Hope he returns as A.I though.Future movies might address this issue.

Comment: too much speculation!

Answer (score -1):

When Vision died, energy was released. When Thanos reversed his death the energy came flooding back. So logic would say if they use the time stone on Tony they would undo the time snap.