# Why didn't they call Captain Marvel for the unsnap?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Spoilers ahead for those that didn't watch Avengers Endgame.

I was reading [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99781/why-didn-t-captain-marvel-put-the-gauntlet-on) and that got me thinking: why didn't Captain Marvel put the gauntlet on the first time for the unsnap instead of Hulk?

I get his speech about how the stones emit mostly gamma rays (or something like that) and he's the best option in that group to survive the stones' power, but isn't Captain Marvel the most powerful of all? (I'm not sure how canon is this but [in an interview](https://nerdist.com/article/captain-marvel-is-the-mcus-most-powerful-hero-according-to-kevin-feige/) Kevin Feige - Marvel Studios chief - said "Captain Marvel... will be by far the strongest character we’ve ever had")

I also understand that she's "superheroing" in some other planet, but wasn't this an important enough mission worth calling her back to Earth?

Comment: Captain Marvel was not even present that time

Comment: @AnkitSharma I get that she was not present _on Earth_ hence my question. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Not the downvoter but she clearly was shown busy in space so I guess they were not obliged to call her every time they need help. And why to call her when they already have hulk who is confident enough?

Comment: **isn't Captain Marvel the most powerful of all?**, I'm sure she isn't

Comment: @Vishwa I added a reference for the "most powerful" thing, I saw similar claim from other sources as well before posting the question.

Comment: @Luciano *Strongest character* and *most powerful being* is completely different things. I dunno what Feige implies, power can be measured in number of parameters. strength, mental and physical, ability to do something etc etc... Anyway this may be personal, but Capt Marvel isn't the most powerful, nah uh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get that she's "superheroing" somewhere else, but wasn't this an important enough mission worth calling her back to Earth?

### She simply wasn't there (or apparently available).

It's already established that she has responsibilities to other planets in the galaxy and wasn't available for the first "unsnap".

Having obtained all the Infinity Stones **there's no point in waiting** to get the job done (even assuming, as has been mentioned elsewhere, Carol **could** have withstood the backlash of the unsnap) and so it fell to Smart-Hulk to do the job.

Of course, then Thanos crosses through time and Captain Marvel returns, *just in time*, to make a pivotal change the the final battle.

Comment: True indeed, I just had the impression she was supposed to do something critical, that her character would be given more importance earlier. I mean perhaps the movie would be 2 hours shorter had they called her :)

Comment: @Luciano also, remember this film is the "swan song" for the original six. For Carol to come in and save the day would remove the importance of the original six in what is their last film together. Carol enters the battle when all of the new guys turn up which can be seen as a figurative passing of the baton.